# Show output while knitting in R Markdown console

Tags: r, r-markdown

In RStudio, when knitting an RMarkdown file, you can see the progress as it knits each chunk.

One of my chunks has a long simulation. Is it possible to output some sort of status info to the R Markdown console?

I've tried `message()` and `warning()`, but they only show up in the html output.

Comment: Set the `message` or `warning` chunk option to `FALSE`.

Comment: Aha, I had `message=FALSE` on the chunk that defined the function, not the one that called it.